# Bootstrap button on mobile, removing focus changes after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, bootstrap-4

After you click a primary bootstrap button, its changes its backgroud color to blue on mobile.

[image]

Here is an example, the first button is how it looks before you click it, second one is after you click it. If I click anywhere around the website the background effect is gone.

How do I make this background not show up\removed by command in js or css. When I click a button?

Here is my button html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 text-center optionsButtonsDiv displayNone">
                                <div class="card bg-light border">
                                    <button onclick="return tryToAnswer(this.id, 0)" runat="server" class="btn btn-outline-primary py-2 py-md-3 optionsButtons">בדיקה</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I've tried this on my CSS, it worked for my computer view, not my mobile view:

```
.optionsButtons:focus, .optionsButtons:active {
outline: none !important;
box-shadow: none;
```

}

Also tried this on js, same result like the first one:

```
window.document.activeElement.blur();
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you click on the button, the styles are applied, but when you click anywhere in the document, the focus style disappears - this is normal focus behavior. Use jquery. for example adding a class with styles to a button.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your CSS:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
.optionsButtons:hover {
    /*Add your button hover styles here*/
}}
```

This will disable the focus effects on mobile, worked perfect for my website!